# How to show the input field value when we click on the other conversation based on userid using reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to reactjs, My objective is how to show the input field (message send text area field) clear when we click on the other user chat conversation. I couldn't find any relevant answers or any example. Can anyone assist me some links or some examples?

Comment: You need to add code that you have tried so far, or else its difficult to help you out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to clear the input when you focus it out. If it this is you case, you could add onBlur event listener to that input. I will show you an example with a class component. First declare a state for each input, you can search the Internet on how to do this dynamically. Then implement handleChange and handleOnBlur functions:

```
state = { 
    inputData: '',
}

handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
}

handleOnBlur = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: '' })
}
```

And finally, declare your input field and bind those functions to it:

```
<input name={inputData} value={this.state.inputData} onChange={this.handleChange} onBlur={this.handleOnBlur} />
```